# Trouble with downloading JSX element (div) as PDF, SVG, or PNG, especially with backend-sourced images

Tags: reactjs, node.js, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm facing an issue with downloading a JSX element (specifically, a div with dynamic content) as a PDF, SVG, or PNG. The download process seems to work fine, and I can see all the content except for an image that is sourced from the backend.

Here's a simplified overview of my code:

```
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
  const downloadPDF = async () =>{
    const capture = document.querySelector('.template-1');
    setLoader(true);

    html2canvas(capture, { scale: 3 }).then((canvas)=>{
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('img/png');

    // Set a specific width and let the height adjust automatically
    const Width = 16; //with cm
    const cmToPx = 37.7952755906; // 1 cm is approximately 37.8 pixels
    const pdfWidth = parseFloat(Width) * cmToPx;
    // const pdfHeight = (canvas.height * pdfWidth) / canvas.width;

    // Calculate the height in pixels based on the original aspect ratio
    const aspectRatio = canvas.width / canvas.height;
    const pdfHeight = pdfWidth / aspectRatio;

      // const doc = new jsPDF('l', 'px', 'a4');
      // Set custom PDF dimensions
    const Height = canvas.height * (pdfWidth / canvas.width);
      const doc = new jsPDF({
        unit: 'px',
        format: 'a0',
        orientation: 'landscape'
      });
      const scale = 4; // You can experiment with different scale factors
      doc.scale(300 * scale); // Adjust the DPI based on the scale factor
      const componentWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
      const componentHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();



      // Convert the height to pixels
      const pdfHeightInPx = pdfHeight * cmToPx;
      doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, pdfWidth, Height);
      setLoader(false);
      doc.save('Label.pdf');
    })
  }
```